# Trying to fill text in input box with dynamic drop down

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I need some help. Chrome (v 75.0.3770.100) using Selenium Basic ChromeDriver (v 75.0.3770.140) in Excel (2013) VBE. There's an input box which generates a dynamic list if the customer id# exists. I wish to fill in the customer id# then select from the dynamic drop down. But first step, I'm struggling to input my text to the box. I'm able to click on the box with

```
obj.FindElementById("selectcustTxt").Click
```

but when I try to fill in the box with:

```
obj.FindElementById("selectcustTxt").Value = "1111"
```

I get an error Run-time error '424': Object required

I tried the following FindElementByXPath with both .Value and .Text but get the same Run-time error '424': Object required

```
obj.FindElementByXPath("//input[@class='form-control cust-autosuggest ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched'][@id='selectcustTxt']").Value = "1111"
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="form-group search-field"><input id="selectcustTxt" type="text" class="form-control cust-autosuggest ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" autocomplete="off" plshholder="Enter Cust name" autocomplepte="off" ng-model="cust" suggest-type="custService" sh-autosuggest="custAddresses" data-validation="required">
```

Comment: HTML looks malformed missing the `<` and `>`. Can you cross check once?

Comment: Apologies, just edited the HTML, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* within the desired element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `FindElementByCss`:

  ```
  obj.FindElementByCss("input.form-control.cust-autosuggest.ng-valid.ng-touched.ng-dirty.ng-valid-parse#selectcustTxt").SendKeys ("1111")
  ```
- Using `FindElementByXPath`:

  ```
  obj.FindElementByXPath("//input[@class='form-control cust-autosuggest ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse' and @id='selectcustTxt']").SendKeys ("1111")
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to send text to some HTML elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60391442/how-to-send-text-to-some-html-elements/60398142#60398142)
- [Need help to fill number into Chrome input box with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57107574/need-help-to-fill-number-into-chrome-input-box-with-selenium/57107749#57107749)