# Element not interactable with Selenium Excel VBA when using SendKeys

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to login to a site and I am using `FindElementById`. In the following code the first part of using `SendKeys` works well but when trying to use the same technique for the password field, I get an error message which tells me that the element is not interactable

```
Sub Test()
Dim bot As New WebDriver

With bot
    .AddArgument "--disable-notifications"
    .Start "Chrome", "https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/"
    .Get "/"
    
    .FindElementById("navbar_username").SendKeys "username"
    .FindElementById("navbar_password").SendKeys "password"
    '.FindElementByName("vb_login_password").SendKeys "password"
    Stop
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: A good reproducible example with clear error message and location (+). Would have benefited from using snippet tool to share the html for the relevant node.

Comment: @QHarr sharing the html is necessary when there is no url but I have attached the url in the code itself so using Inspect would be more useful.

Comment: I love having the url present but not everyone may be able to access it. In this case it looks like a pretty accessible one. It was just an observation/suggestion. I was already overjoyed at having a reproducible example hence the upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close. The **Password** field with *id* attribute as **`navbar_password`** is having the property:

```
style="display: none;"
```

So you won't be able to interact with the element.

---

To send a *character sequence* both to the **User Name** and **Password** field you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `FindElementById()`:

  ```
  .FindElementById("navbar_username").SendKeys "username"
  .FindElementById("navbar_password_hint").SendKeys "password"
  ```
- Using `FindElementByCss()`:

  ```
  .FindElementByCss("input#navbar_username").SendKeys "username"
  .FindElementByCss("input#navbar_password_hint").SendKeys "password"
  ```
- Using `FindElementByXPath()`:

  ```
  .FindElementByXPath("//input[@id='navbar_username']").SendKeys "username"
  .FindElementByXPath("//input[@id='navbar_password_hint']").SendKeys "password"
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of revelant discussions in:

- [Trying to fill text in input box with dynamic drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57082285/trying-to-fill-text-in-input-box-with-dynamic-drop-down/57082454#57082454)
- [Need help to fill number into Chrome input box with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57107574/need-help-to-fill-number-into-chrome-input-box-with-selenium/57107749#57107749)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked when I run the code step by step so I found out that I have to wait a little before sending the data to password field.

Comment: How can I make the waiting is restricted to the element when it is available? I mean loop until element is ready to receive the data.

Comment: @YasserKhalil Gimme some time, let me look at the VB code, then I will get back to you

Answer (score 1):

Try referring this [webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868009/how-to-resolve-elementnotinteractableexception-element-is-not-visible-in-seleni)

The page you are trying to access has added a web element over another web element. i.e web element of id navbar_password_hint over web element of id navbar_password. Try referring above link to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems only I have to put a waiting line before what you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the element state is not clickable. You have to use webdriver wait property and make sure that element state is clickable

```
 WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    WebElement e= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("xpath_of_element")));
    e.click();
```