# How to send text to some HTML elements through Selenium VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I have been having trouble on referring to a search box on a website through Selenium in VBA. The HTML code of the box is:

```
<input type = "search" class ="form-control input-sm"
placeholder aria-controls="result_table"> ==$0
```

I have tried

```
bot.findElementByCssSelector(".form-control").SendKeys ("werresf")
bot.findElementByCssSelector(".form-control.input-sm").SendKeys ("werresf")
bot.findElementByCssSelector(".input-sm").SendKeys ("werresf")
bot.findElementByCssSelector(".form-control input-sm").SendKeys ("werresf")
bot.findElementByClassName("form-control input-sm").SendKeys ("werresf")
```

But none of them seems to work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `bot.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".form-control"));` ?

Comment: Yes I have, but it does not work unfortunately. It gives object required error by this way. When I try to findElementByClassName it gives another error. When I try to findElementByCssSelector it does not give any error but it does not do anything either.

Comment: `bot.findElementByCssSelector(".form-control.input-sm").SendKeys ("werresf")` should work in your case. But you might have multiple items matching with that CSS and Selenium will pick the first element in that case, which might be a hidden element. So please test your css `.form-control.input-sm` in the browser devtools and then select the right item. Also make sure you point to the right frame, if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* within the desired element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `FindElementByCss`:

  ```
  bot.FindElementByCss("input.form-control.input-sm[aria-controls='result_table']").SendKeys ("werresf")
  ```
- Using `FindElementByXPath`:

  ```
  bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@class='form-control input-sm' and @aria-controls='result_table']").SendKeys ("werresf")
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Trying to fill text in input box with dynamic drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57082285/trying-to-fill-text-in-input-box-with-dynamic-drop-down/57082454#57082454)
- [Need help to fill number into Chrome input box with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57107574/need-help-to-fill-number-into-chrome-input-box-with-selenium/57107749#57107749)

Comment: The second one worked. Thank you so much man. I have tried using XPath before but I did not come across "and @aria-controls='result_table'" part when I copied the XPath from the webpage. Did you use a different method on getting the XPath?

Comment: @KKB That was my bad, there was an error within the first locator, which I have corrected now. I din't use any different method, rather you are free to choose any attribute. Let me know if you have further queries.

Comment: After a bit of tinkering, I found out that one should replace the double quotes on the copied XPath with single quotes, this way, the VBA editor does not give a syntax error and it works like a charm. I will definitely let you know if I have further queries. Thanks again.